# ¿Cómo linkear un archivo del directorio /web desde localhost:8000 en Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, symfony

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto symfony local al que accedo por `localhost:8000` después de encender el servidor con `"php bin\console server:run"`.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo generar una url para los archivos públicos que están en la carpeta `/web`?

Cuando trabajo con xampp lo hago de esta forma: `localhost/my_project/web/filename.jpg`

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a SOes. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta al español?

Comment: Hi.. The official language of the site is spanish. If spanish if your language, please translate the question.

Comment: Ya la pasé a español.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad... ` localhost:8000/my_project/web/filename.jpg` no funciona?

Comment: No @Muriano , no funciona

Comment: Es posible que el servidor embebido apunte a `web` como directorio base, prueba con esto otro:  localhost:8000/filename.jpg, vamos a ir eliminando opciones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enlazar a tus css, javascript o imágenes que tengas en el directorio web/ tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" />

{# ... #}

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Para más información puedes verlo en la documentación de Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html